# Signed Applet for Intranet app

Tags: java, security, plugins, browser, applet

Is it possible to have self-signed Applets without restrictions in local network? I can configure my user's PCs since they are all in LAN.

The idea is that I self-sign Applet, and out IT department edits client's PCs, so that they auto trust our Applets.

Is this possible, or are there any restrictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is an url where they explain how to solve your problem

http://www.jade-cheng.com/uh/ta/signed-applet-tutorial/

Comment: Is there a way also to avoid various messages to user's browser about Java plugins beeing used, should I import this certificate in user's OS or just in Java, or is it the same?

Comment: Do i need to import generated certificates in user's browsers, or is it enough to import them in Java Panel, or somewhere in OS?

Comment: You have to add it into browser